# Can't set HTTP Response header in ASP.NET/IIS7 classic mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

There is a HttpModule that change Server field in Response Headers. But it does not work in  ASP.NET/IIS7 classic mode. what is the solution for remove or change Server field in reponse header?

```
public class CloakHttpHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.PreSendRequestHeaders += new EventHandler(context_PreSendRequestHeaders);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void context_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        context.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "Apache 2.0");
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Server", "WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.1");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this unless you're running at least IIS7, Integrated Pipeline Mode and .NET 3.0. The documentation states this:

> [HttpResponse.Headers Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx)
>
> The Headers property is only supported with the IIS 7.0 integrated
>   pipeline mode and at least the .NET Framework 3.0. When you try to
>   access the Headers property and either of these two conditions is not
>   met, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown.

Comment: Too bad, I have SSRS 2012, it uses .NET Framework 2.0 and runs on IIS < 7 ... and now it doesn't work because of SameSite-Requirement in Chrome...